# Que signifie le conditionnel dans le titre d'un article de presse ?

Tags: grammaire, sens, conditionnel, titres

Dans le titre de [cet article](http://www.lemonde.fr/technologies/article/2013/07/09/edward-snowden-aurait-accepte-la-proposition-d-asile-du-venezuela_3445044_651865.html) apparaît un conditionnel:

> Edward Snowden *aurait* accepté la proposition d'asile du Venezuela.

"[Il] aurait accepté".  Je suppose que ça veut dire (en anglais) "*he has accepted*", mais pourquoi pas "il a accepté", le passé composé?

Comment: En anglais, cela se traduirait par "He allegedly accepted" ou "Edward Snowden may have accepted/appears to have accepted" puisque cela n'est pas nécessairement confirmé.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Les journalistes écrivent souvent au conditionnel quand, pour une raison ou une autre (p.e. une source unique, des sources contradictoires, risque de désinformation — en particulier en rapportant des déclarations d'un intervenant —, pure précaution) ils ne veulent pas s'engager sur la réalité du fait (ce qui d'ailleurs est la valeur de base du conditionnel, le contexte est juste plus propice à son emploi).

Dans le cas présent, la phrase qui suit : « Ni l'intéressé, ni WikiLeaks, qui a relayé récemment ses propos, n'ont confirmé cette information. » suffit à expliquer le conditionnel.

Answer (score 6):

Dans le titre d'un article, un fait présenté au conditionnel indique que l'information doit être vérifiée. L'article va probablement détailler des indices ou des paroles reportées qui corroborent cette thèse, sans que celle-ci soit pour l'instant vérifiable.

Voici l'extrait de la page [Conditionnel](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditionnel) sur Wikipédia qui décrit cet emploi :

> Le conditionnel est également employé au lieu d'un temps de l'indicatif pour exprimer qu'on tient cette information d'une source non certaine ; dans ce cas-là, le couplage avec l'imparfait n'est pas nécessaire.

Answer (score 1):

Les journalistes utilisent souvent le conditionnel pour se couvrir en cas de fausse information.

La plupart du temps, ils souhaitent donner l'information le plus vite possible, notamment avant les concurrents et oublient donc volontairement de confirmer leur source. Ça leur permet parfois de faire le buzz.

Comment: Euh, des fois il est légitime de présenter des indices même si ils ne suffisent pas à prouver les faits, l'information n'est parfois simplement pas disponible malgré un vrai travail de fond. Ta réponse est un commentaire sans rapport avec la question.