# "Considérant les conditions comme remplies, il se disposerait à verser la somme." – Will he pay or not?

Tags: sens, conditionnel

Are the conditions totally fulfilled and will the payment be made for sure if I read in a newspaper this:

"***On assure que le groupe financier (considérant les conditions d'achat comme remplies) se disposerait à verser la somme promise.***"

Does "comme remplies" mean the conditions are fulfilled 100% or it is just as if they are fulfilled?

Does "il se disposerait à verser la somme" mean the money will be paid with certitude or it is not quite clear what will happen.

This is the original text:
"*On assure que le groupe financier de M. Lazare Weiller, considérant les conditions d'achat comme remplies, se disposerait à verser à Wright la moitié de la somme promise (250,000 fr.) l'autre moitié payable lorsque l'aviateur aura instruit les trois élèves qu'il s'est engagé à former.*" ([Source](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k6550620m/f410.item.zoom))

This is my English version, I am not sure about it.
"*We give assurances that the financial group of Mr. Lazare Weiller, considering the purchase conditions as fulfilled, would be ready to pay Wright half the promised sum (250,000 fr.) The other half is payable when the aviator instructs the three students he committed himself to train.*"

Comment: I won't make an answer of it but your translation is correct as far as I know. "Comme remplies" is "fulfilled" as you said and "Il se disposerait" is conditional because the journalist is'nt sure of it, you can't report about the intention of someone before he acts.

Comment: about conditionnal in newspapers: [see this question](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/6832/7321)

Answer (score 2):

Using conditional or present for the verbs "disposer" are both correct grammatically but it changes the meaning of the phrases.

Here the use of conditional implies a future action : " we insure that the financial group (regarding fulfilled purchase conditions) will proceed to the payment of the promised sum of money".
It means the purchase conditions have to fulfilled before they pay.
You could see this kind of phrases on official contracts for examples.
If you use the present : "On assure que le groupe financier (considérant les conditions d'achat comme remplies) se disposent à verser la somme promise."/"we insure that the financial group (regarding fulfilled purchase conditions) proceed/are proceeding to the payment of the promised sum of money". 
You could see it means here that the purchase conditions have already been fulfilled and they pay. 
Hoping it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

There are layers of "condensed" grammar and "hedging" to not state pure facts here. It could be translated roughly as

> Sources/people are saying that Mr. L. W.'s group considers that the buy conditions are fulfilled and is preparing to pay Mr. Wright half the agreed sum (250K francs). The other half is to be paid once the aviator will be done teaching the three students he has committed to train.

1. *On* is used in its impersonal meaning. Without a broader context, I'm used *Sources*. (It's really short for *on nous assure*)
2. The conditional here provides extra hedging on top of the *on*. I seem to recall (but may be wrong) that *would* is not available in this context in English. Present indicative would also be grammatical, but conditional is more usual.