# usage of conditional in news

Tags: grammaire, mode-grammatical, conditionnel

I am reading [French news (supposedly Francais Facile)](https://savoirs.rfi.fr/fr/apprendre-enseigner/langue-francaise/journal-en-francais-facile-24052017-20h00-gmt) and a usage of conditional has me confused.

> Le président philippin l'a annoncé lui-même mais au conditionnel : le chef de la police de Malabang aurait été décapité à un barrage contrôlé par les rebelles. Quinze personnes dont des religieuses et un prêtre auraient été enlevés dans une cathédrale de Marawi, selon l'évêque de la ville

Even though the first phrase contains "au conditionnel", I am confused by the usage of the conditional mood here. What does this mean ?

In other instances, I believe I do understand the usage of the conditional mood.

thanks

Comment: Same reason as here: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6832/que-signifie-le-conditionnel-dans-le-titre-dun-article-de-presse.

Comment: Indeed -- "If this information is true, it would mean the chief of police was decapitated."