# Pourquoi utiliser le conditionnel passé : « Une manifestation aurait rassemblé...»

Tags: grammaire, conditionnel

Je ne comprends pas pourquoi on emploie le conditionnel passé ici :

> Une manifestation *aurait rassemblé* quelques centaines de militants.

Quelle serait la différence entre cette phrase et celle-ci :

> Une manifestation *rassemblerait* quelques centaines de militants.

Est-ce que  la première fait part d'un doute plus grand ?

Comment: Depending on the context of your sentence, [this question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6832/que-signifie-le-conditionnel-dans-le-titre-dun-article-de-presse) might be related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La première phrase *(« Une manifestation aurait rassemblé quelques centaines de militants. »)* est ambiguë, et peut se comprendre d'au moins trois manières :

- la manifestation n’a pas eu lieu quand elle eût été possible ;
- la manifestation a eu lieu, est peut-être même encore en cours, mais on ne connaît pas exactement le nombre des participants et on se fie à une source quelconque pour donner un nombre ;
- on dit qu’une manifestation aurait eu lieu, mais on n’a pas encore trouvé de moyen de confirmer avec certitude qu'elle ait eu lieu (bon, c'est peu envisageable pour un événement courant, mais pour un évènement historique ou en un lieu particulièrement retiré, on pourrait encore croire que c'est possible ; sinon, on pourra penser à autre chose qu’à une manifestation, par exemple une observation d’un rhinocéros en liberté dans une petite ville de France).

La seconde phrase *(« Une manifestation rassemblerait quelques centaines de militants. »)* peut aussi s’interpréter de différentes manières. Voici deux cas possibles :

- Soit on parle d’une manifestation qui n’a pas encore eu lieu, qui peut-être se planifie ou peut-être n’existe qu’en pensée sans réelle volonté de la mettre en place (elle pourrait être perçue comme trop risquée, trop petite, ou autre chose).
- Soit un parle d’une manifestation qui pourrait avoir lieu présentement, selon certaines sources (peu sûres et/ou en petit nombre). C’est la version encore en cour de la troisième possibilité évoquée ci-dessus pour l’autre conjugaison (pour laquelle elle était terminée).

---

Mmerci à [cet utilisateur](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/20684) pour son pertinent commentaire sur la deuxième option possible de la seconde phrase.

Answer (score 2):

Dans la première phrase  il s'agit d'une manifestation passée ou qui est en cours.
Le nombre des militants est mis en doute : il pourrait ne pas y avoir eu même une centaine de militants ou possiblement il pourrait y avoir eu plus.

Dans la seconde il s'agit d'une manifestation hypothétique. On émet une évaluation sur le nombre possible des militants qui peuvent être rassemblés, cela en fonction de conditions qui sont à préciser mais qui ne le sont pas toujours dans la suite ou dans ce qui est dit avant cette phrase.
Cette phrase-ci pourrait être utilisée au même effet que la précédente mais le locuteur préfèrera le plus souvent la modifier légèrement pour lui donner plus de spécificité ;

- Une manifestation en cours rassemblerait quelques centaines de militants.
- On me signale une manifestation qui rassemblerait  quelques centaines de militants.

Answer (score 2):

La manif dont on parle dans la première phrase n'a pas eu lieu, et l'occasion de la faire est déjà perdue dans le passé.
Tandis que la manif de la seconde phrase est encore possible. 
Je n'ai pas d'argument grammatical, j'ai appris le français étant enfant, avec un ancien bourgeois riche (maître de langues étrangères pour la survie), exproprié dans les années 1945 en Roumanie, alors occupée par l'URSS et forcée au communisme.

Comment: Bien sûr que si la manifestation a eu lieu, mais on ne sait pas combien de personnes exactement elle a rassemblées.

Comment: « ancien bourgeois riche » n'est pas compréhensible ; un  riche bourgeois qui n'était plus un bourgeois et était devenu un maitre : un ancien bourgeois qui avait été riche.